# Show block (with page breaks) for fixed time

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I want to set up a block with a number of questions (and page breaks), which after exactly 2 minutes will progress to the next block, regardless of what the subject has accomplished / clicked / performed in that block.

I set variables in the embedded data: TimeLeft1 = 120, TimeFlag1 = 0, and wrote the following code in each question in the block-

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var timeleft1 = parseInt("${e://Field/TimeLeft1}");
    
    var timeflag1 = parseInt("${e://Field/TimeFlag1}");
    
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if (timeleft1<=0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            timeflag1 = 1;
            $('NextButton').click();
        }
        timeleft1--;
    }, 1000);
    
    $('NextButton').onclick = function(event){
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('TimeLeft1',timeleft1);
        
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("TimeFlag1",timeflag1);
    }
        

});
```

after that, I insert display logic, which display "if flag = 1".
Unfortunately, the survey doesn't proceed after 2 minutes, and the block that should appear, not appear..

If anyone can help, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What is `parseInt("${e://Field/TimeLeft1})");`? That looks like an odd combination of a template literal (But not using backticks) and a file path, I'm not sure how you will get any int other than `1` out of it (Or perhaps NaN, not sure how well JS will handle those symbols)

Comment: It's an attempt to access the variable defined in embedded data - "TimeLeft1"

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Qualtrics myself, but I would expect there to be a `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData()` if there is a `setEmbeddedData`, so that might be worth having a look for in their documentation.

Comment: That is how we read embedded data in the JS in Qualtrics